# How to consider data that is similar within a JSON object file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I am building an application to identify duplicated and unique data in a JSON file and I want to output the number of Unique records.

I have the a JSON object which has lots of first names and last names. I want to be able to identify duplicate data but also if the names are similar it should identify the data as the same. For example:

```
 [
   {FirstName: 'Joshua', LastName: 'smith'}
   {FirstName: 'Joshuaa', LastName: 'smith'}
 ]
```

As you see above the second object has an extra 'a' but I want this to be considered as the same piece of the data as the first object. So basically take into consideration typo's within the data for both FirstName and LastName.

I thought about using Regex but I cant figure where to use it.

Comment: "I thought about using Regex but I cant figure where to use it." - Well in the same code/function where you will parse this data of course! :)

Comment: The tough part is how "similar" you want it to be.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/3576273/2506522

Comment: Hi Guys, 

So in my application, the data I read is from an CSV file. My application is a React app, I have an import feature so when the user click the file to import this parses the data to state object.

I would like the to data to be similar by one letter in each firstName and lastName

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, setting a THRESHOLD value you want for similarity, I setted 1 in this example:

```
const array = [
    { FirstName: 'Joshua', LastName: 'smith' },
    { FirstName: 'Joshuaa', LastName: 'smith' }
];

const THRESHOLD = 1;

const compareCollections = (document) => {
    array.forEach(element => {
        let consideredSimilar = false;

        if (element.FirstName === document.FirstName) {
            // typo should be in the lastname
            if (_checkDifferences(element.LastName, document.LastName) <= THRESHOLD) {
                // they can be similar
                console.log('SIMILAR LASTNAME');
                consideredSimilar = true;
            }
        } else if (element.LastName === document.LastName) {
            // typo should be in firstname
            if (_checkDifferences(element.FirstName, document.FirstName) <= THRESHOLD) {
                // they can be similar
                console.log('SIMILAR FIRSTNAME');
                consideredSimilar = true;
            }
        }

        console.log('CONSIDERED SIMILAR: ', consideredSimilar);

    });
}

const _checkDifferences= (first, second) => {
    const splittedFirst = first.split('');
    const splittedSecond = second.split('');

    const length = splittedFirst.length > splittedSecond.length ? splittedFirst.length : splittedSecond.length;

    let differences = 0;

    for (let index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        const elementFirst = splittedFirst[index];
        const elementSecond = splittedSecond[index];

        if (elementFirst != elementSecond) {
            differences++;
        }
    }

    return differences;
}

compareCollections(array[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about duplicate, lets clarify what duplicity is. I might figure out situation when person has a real name - "Joshuaa". In terms of your question it might be some sort of [bayesian filter](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.107.7415&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

As for me, simple convert you array into object with key as lastname (its cheap), and back to array.

```
const array = [
    { FirstName: 'Joshua', LastName: 'smith' },
    { FirstName: 'Joshuaa', LastName: 'smith' }
];

const test = array.reduce((acc, el) => ({
    ...acc,
  [el.LastName]: {...el}
}), {});
const output = Object.values(test);
```